# Run gulp "npm start" from a php document?

Tags: php, node.js, shell, npm, gulp

Im trying to run a shell command for gulp to compile.

i usually run:

```
cd
cd /var/www/html/
npm uninstall gulp --save
npm install gulp --save

npm start
```

and the gulp file compiles well.

I need to know if theres a way to compile the gulp file (essentially running the npm start  command from a php document.

```
$output = shell_exec('./compileNpmStart.sh');

// display $output
echo $output;
```

This does seem to compile but:

After compilation i got a log file instead of correct compilation.

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.1.2
3 info using node@v7.5.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~prestart: base-prep@1.0.0
6 warn lifecycle npm is using /usr/bin/nodejs but there is no node binary in the current PATH. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.
7 silly lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
8 info lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~start: base-prep@1.0.0
9 verbose lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
10 verbose lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~start: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/node-gyp-bin:/var/www/html/node_modules/.bin
11 verbose lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~start: CWD: /var/www/html
12 silly lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '-c', 'gulp serve' ]
13 info lifecycle base-prep@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: base-prep@1.0.0 start: `gulp serve`
14 verbose stack spawn sh ENOENT
14 verbose stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:1023:11)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
14 verbose stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:359:16)
14 verbose stack     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
14 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
15 verbose pkgid base-prep@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd /var/www/html
17 error Linux 4.8.6-x86_64-linode78
18 error argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
19 error node v7.5.0
20 error npm  v4.1.2
21 error file sh
22 error path sh
23 error code ELIFECYCLE
24 error errno ENOENT
25 error syscall spawn sh
26 error base-prep@1.0.0 start: `gulp serve`
26 error spawn sh ENOENT
27 error Failed at the base-prep@1.0.0 start script 'gulp serve'.
27 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
27 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the base-prep package,
27 error not with npm itself.
27 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
27 error     gulp serve
27 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
27 error     npm bugs base-prep
27 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
27 error     npm owner ls base-prep
27 error There is likely additional logging output above.
28 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: lookup shell_exec

Comment: I tryed shell_exec, System(), exec() and a few more.none of them seem to work. I think there may be some kind of permission error. tryed installing webconsole.php and running the command from a webbased http://web-console.org/ terminal. got permission errors.

Comment: have you tried creating a shell script with SUID and executing it?

Comment: I havent. Il try it now and see if it works for me.

Comment: Not working unortunitly

Comment: Niraj Shah -- I update the question after your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by saving the script you want to run in a file, e.g. `compile.sh`. Give the script the correct run permissions, e.g. `chmod 755 compile.sh`.

Then, in your PHP script, add the following:

```
<?php
// allow script to run for up to 10 minutes
set_time_limit(600); // seconds

// output of script will be saved in $output
$output = shell_exec('./compile.sh');

// display $output
echo $output;
```

This should be enough for you to run the script using PHP.

You may need to reference `npm` and any directories using absolute path. Run `which npm` via command line to get the full path to use. Run the script via the command line to make sure it works.

Comment: Tryed that. it does seem to run the script but no actuall effect on the server files.

Comment: file permissions are 777 for the compile.sh file that has the sh script

Comment: Run `./compile.sh` manually via command line and make sure there are no errors with the script itself. You may also need to reference `npm` as absolute path.

Comment: Does seem to work fine. although i did notice - and this is normal - the compiling proccess takes about 8 minutes. i know the php running the script will not show the lie progress but does the background php running the command.sh have a server side cuttof for how long it can run shell proccesses?

Comment: You can modify how long the script is allowed to run by adding the following line to your code: `set_time_limit ( 600 )` (10 minutes limit).